# is multiple assignments of atomic variables, an atomic operation?

Tags: c++, atomic

consider I have two atomic booleans as follows.

```
private:
    std::atomic_bool x;
    std::atomic_bool y;
```

Can I say the following operation is atomic? or do I have to use `lock_guard` to to make sure they are assigned together?

```
x = y = true; // are two bools assigned together atomically?
```

also consider in another thread I want to read these booleans.

```
if(!x && !y) ...
```

my assumption is that this is not atomic, maybe its better to use `atomic<int>` instead?

Comment: different question,but somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858387/stdatomic-treat-a-pair-of-atomic-int32-as-one-atomic-int64

Comment: @RickAstley I don't see how that follows. `x.store` promises that the action of assigning to `x` is atomic; it doesn't say anything about whether evaluating its argument is atomic with that. It also just clearly doesn't make sense; by your reasoning you can store the result of a huge function, and make the whole function atomic. Now your atomic variable (which could just be a simple bool) is acting as a mutex.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it is not. All that an atomic operation guarantees is that no intervening operation happens on the variable. In your example it is entirely possible that `y` gets assigned, something unrelated happens (but only in another thread; in the current thread re-ordering will not happen because of the memory fence implied by `operator=` on an atomic), and then `x` gets assigned. The same is true when reading them.

If you really want these operations to be atomic, you'll need to use a single atomic type that encapsulates both pieces of information. There's many ways to do this; you can use a char and utilize different bits at the cost of some bit masking operations, you can use a 16 bit integer, but I will illustrate with the clearest (IMHO) approach: a struct with two booleans.

```
struct MyBools {
  bool x;
  bool y;
};

bool operator==(const MyBools& lhs, const MyBools& rhs) {
    return lhs.x == rhs.x && lhs.y == rhs.y;
}

using MyAtomicBools = std::atomic<MyBools>;

MyAtomicBools b{true, true};
...
if (b == MyBools{false, false}) { ... }
```

This may or may not optimize as well as using a 16 bit integer and casting out the two booleans by hand. gcc seems to optimize this extremely well; it turns the set operation into a single write + memory fence, but clang doesn't do as well: https://godbolt.org/g/moiT9Y.

Comment: thanks. I tried to use atomic 16 bit integer but that made reading part a little complicated. using struct with descriptive and individual fields is good suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

```
x = y = true; // are two bools assigned together atomically?
```

That line is clearly not an atomic operation as x and y are in two different locations in memory: it is impossible to set two locations that are not continuous³ one each other at the same time.

The atomic word implies that read or write is done in one cpu cycle¹, so one variable is safe, but x and y are ***two*** ***different*** atomic variables.

If you have any doubts about don't hesitate to look at the binary code produced, through the use of a disassembler.

```
if(!x && !y) ...
```

The same: the CPU have to access the value of the ***two***  ***different*** variables by copying the values into it own registers, make a boolean evaluation, negate, and perform an evaluation²; clearly not atomic operations.

¹ it surely is not so simple, but from a *higher language* developper point of view, you should think that
² again it is not so simple, as the compiler can make optimizations, and the CPU can make some things by itself
³ even with continuous locations, the total size must be readable/writable in one loop: 1Mo of data is clearly not readable in one loop by the cpu, even if all the data was continuously side by side.

Comment: You have some misconceptions about what `std::atomic` is. It's a standard that allows writing cross platform atomic code. The size of the CPU register or "one loop" is totally irrelevant (except of course for performance). Also, the word atomic does *not* mean one CPU cycle. It just means that nothing can happen to the variable in between. FYI the atomic template can be instantiated with types as large as you want: "std::atomic may be instantiated with any TriviallyCopyable type T". http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic

Comment: I understand that (I'm both C and C++ developper), but to explain simply the subject it appeared to me simpler to be more close to the hardware, as atomic is to be understood as its C counterparts (sig_atomic_t).

it was just a simplification for educational purposes.